# svg fill-rule applied to two or more polygons

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to apply the svg evenodd [fill-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) in two or more polygons that one is inside/intersects the other.

In the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLjwgR) i would like the small polygon cube to be white.

```
<svg height="500" width="500" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" >
 <polygon points="100,100,300,100,300,300,100,300"/>  
 <polygon points="150,150,200,150,200,200,150,200" />  
</svg>
```

How can I achieve this using the fill-rule attribute?

Should I use another shape?

Please keep in mind that in order to construct any shape I will have to use the points attribute to provide coordinates of shapes.

Comment: The fill rule only applies to single shapes. You'd need to merge the two polygons into a single path to get it to work.

Comment: is there a way to create a shape which 'includes' other shapes? Could you give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: Yes, use a path. <path d="some list of M and L commands"/>

Comment: Is there a solution other than path? It would mean I would have to make changes to the coordinates I use

Comment: You could create a clipPath that contains one of the polygons and use it to clip the other polygon maybe.

Comment: If you're just looking for overlapping regions to be colored differently, you might want to explore a filter